# AngularJs $http timeout response code

Tags: angularjs

If I have

```
$http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {})
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
```

what value would `status` have if ther were a timeout (no internet connection). Would it just be 404?

Comment: You will get `status === -1`.

Comment: Can't you just turn off internet and check it yourself?

Comment: Lollx! I am developing on localhost & didn't think of that (it had been along day - rise at 5:30am, 2 hours commute, 11 hours coding, 2 hour commute, then coding at hme until I posted that at 11:30pm before retiring). It seems obvious now

Comment: @Hamlwt I can confirm that I have tested and you are corrrect. Feel free to post that as an answer and I will award it, so as to help others in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sicne @HamletHakobyan won't post an answer, I will point out that his comment was correct - status is -1